# react-monaco-editor blackout... TypeError: Cannot read property 'pushUndoStop' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, monaco-editor

I use `"react-monaco-editor"` for my project.

```
import { MonacoDiffEditor } from 'react-monaco-editor';

...

<MonacoDiffEditor
  width="1140"
  height="520"
  language="javascript"
  theme="vs-dark"
  original={this.props.original}
  value={this.props.current}
  options={{
    renderSideBySide: true,
  }}
  editorDidMount={this.editorDidMount}
/>
```

This error can only be viewed after deploy my server.

> simpleWorker.js:25 Could not create web worker(s). Falling back to
> loading web worker code in main thread, which might cause UI freezes.
> Please see https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor#faq el @
> simpleWorker.js:25 simpleWorker.js:28 You must define a function
> MonacoEnvironment.getWorkerUrl or MonacoEnvironment.getWorker el @
> simpleWorker.js:28 react-dom.production.min.js:5058 TypeError: Cannot
> read property 'pushUndoStop' of undefined
> at l.value (diff.js:283)
> at ls (react-dom.production.min.js:5163)
> at react-dom.production.min.js:6408
> at t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:309)
> at Ui (react-dom.production.min.js:2816)
> at Cl (react-dom.production.min.js:6204)
> at cl (react-dom.production.min.js:5895)
> at react-dom.production.min.js:2851
> at t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:309)
> at Ui (react-dom.production.min.js:2816) rs @ react-dom.production.min.js:5058

I test in local with `nginx`, but only serviceWorker warnings logged.
I think that `ServiceWorker` warnings are http environment in my server.

What is `pushUndoStop...` I really don't know this error.
help me...

Comment: my package.json
"react-monaco-editor": "^0.35.0",

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you fixed this issue or not by now, since it has been a while, but in case anyone else lands here, I got this issue too. I had `v0.20.0` of `monaco-editor` and `v0.35.0` `react-monaco-editor` which worked fine. Then I updated to `v0.23.0` and I ran into this issue as a regression. I then tried `v0.25.2` with no change. After that I tried updating `react-monaco-editor` to the `v0.43.0` and the problem stopped happening! I'm thinking it is an issue where they made a change in `monaco-editor` and if you didn't update `react-monaco-editor` to a newer version it would break with that error.